# QComboBox currentIndex() to hide other widgets

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer, qcombobox

**What it should do**: When the `QComboBox` is on the first item (index 0) it should hide the `QStackedWidget`. Which causes the `QComboBox` to extend as much as possible. As soon as you change the item in the `QComboBox` to anything, the `QComboxBox` should shrink and the `QStackedWidget` should display the correct page.

[image]

**What I have and what it does instead**: I test what the current index item is of the `QComboBox` and depending on that I change the size policies and visibility of widgets in order to obtain what I want. But it doesn't work. I tried to do workarounds but I cant seem to figure this out.

I also used `qDebug()` to see what currentIndexItem returns, and it seems to be stuck at 0, no matter to what index I change the `QComboBox` to. Do I have to update the currentItemIndex?

[image]

Note: I have a signal connected in the designer from `QComboBox` to QStackedWidget: `currentIndexChanged(int) -> setCurrentIndex(int)`

Here is my code.

**My code**:

*interfacewindow.h*

```
#ifndef INTERFACEWINDOW_H
#define INTERFACEWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QComboBox>

namespace Ui
{
    class InterfaceWindow;
}

class InterfaceWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit InterfaceWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~InterfaceWindow();

private:
    Ui::InterfaceWindow *ui;

private slots:
    void on_actionClose_triggered();
};

#endif // INTERFACEWINDOW_H
```

*interfacewindow.cpp*

```
#include "interfacewindow.h"
#include "ui_interfacewindow.h"
#include <QDebug>

InterfaceWindow::InterfaceWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::InterfaceWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    if(ui->comboBox->currentIndex() == 0)
    {
        ui->comboBox->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
        ui->stackedWidget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Maximum, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
        ui->stackedWidget->setVisible(false);
    }
    else
    {
        ui->comboBox->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Maximum, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
        ui->stackedWidget->setVisible(true);
    }
}

InterfaceWindow::~InterfaceWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void InterfaceWindow::on_actionClose_triggered()
{
    this->close();
}
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include <QApplication>

#include "interfacewindow.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    InterfaceWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: It looks like the only place you take an action based on the state of ui->comboBox->currentIndex() is inside your InterfaceWindow class's constructor method.  If you want your setSizePolicy()/setVisible() code to execute in response to a change of the QComboBox's state, you'll need to move it into a slot instead, and connect the QComboBox's currentIndexChanged() method to that slot-method.  (You may want to manually call that slot-method from within the constructor as well, just to set up the initial state of the window to the desired state corresponding the QComboBox's initial state)

Comment: Alright i'll try that

Comment: That worked perfectly. I added a slot to the interface window and it gets triggered each time the combobox is activated? Like so:

`connect(ui->comboBox, SIGNAL(activated(int)), this, SLOT(trigger(int)))`

All the if statement from the constructor got moved to this slot and now it works perfectly.